# the K-th sum between every 2 elements in a vector

Tags: java, arrays, vector, sum, complexity-theory

I'm given a vector and I have to find the K-th sum of every 2 elements. We suppose that we sort the sums.

For examples say I have the vector {1 4 5 6} and I need the 4th sum. All sums are:

- 1 + 1 = 2
- 1 + 4 = 5
- 4 + 1 = 5
- 1 + 5 = 6
- 5 + 1 = 6
- 1 + 6 = 7

etc.

The fourth sum is 6.

I know that the optimal solution should be in O(n*log n) but there are some things I can't quite figure out. The only solution I've come up with is the really obvious one where you calculate the sums and sort them and then pick the K-th one.

Comment: We should be called `homeworkoverflow.com`.

Comment: And what do you have until now?

Comment: What about 4 + 5? which 'k' is that?

Comment: if the answer is 4 + 5 then k would have to be 7. I have already said what I have until now. Or do you mean the code?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, you're right.

Comment: So is 4+5 for k=8? And then 5+4 for k=9?

Comment: yes. It really makes no difference if you switch those 2 because your answer would still be 9.

Comment: you're doing 1+1 at the beginning? Do you ever have 4+4 or 5+5 and so on? If so, which K are they?

Comment: The whole list : 1 + 1 = 2; 1 + 4 = 5; 4 + 1 = 5; 1 + 5 = 6; 5 + 1 = 6; 1 + 6 = 7; 6 + 1 = 7; 4 + 4 = 8; 4 + 5 = 9; 5 + 4 = 9;  4 + 6 = 10; 6 + 4 = 10; 5 + 5 = 10; 5 + 6 = 11; 6 + 5 = 11; 6 + 6 = 12 . 4 + 4 has k = 8 . 5 + 5 has k =  12. But rlly the question is more like which sum is at k = 12 (let's say. And you answer will be 10.

Comment: Yeah, i get that, but you need to know what to Ks are to know. Anyway, I've written an idea of what your solution could be like. I hope it helps. It seems like it can be easily achieved in O(n).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your example can be boiled down to this:

- K=1 : 1st element with itself
- K=2,3 : 1st element with 2nd element
- K=4,5 : 1st element with 3rd element
- K=6,7 : 1st element with 4th element
- K=8 : 2nd element with itself
- K=9,10 : 2nd element with 3rd element
- K=11,12 : 2nd element with 4th element
- K=13 : 3rd element with itself
- K=14,15 : 3rd element with 4th element
- K=16 : 4th element with itself

So what you have is:

- 1st element with itself
- N element pairs (1 with 2, 2 with 1 etc) : 2*(N-1)
- 2nd element with itself.
- (N-1) element pairs (2 with 3, 3 with 2 etc):  2*(N-2)
- 3rd element with itself
- (N-2) element pairs (3 with 4, 4 with 3 etc) : 2*(N-3)
- 4th element with itself

And so on. So you can easily find in O(n) your "main" element and then simply find using another O(n) loop your k element.

Comment: Try that with input `1,10,100,1000` and your algorithm will fail.